# npx create-next-app asks me if I want to use TypeScript, but won't take no for an answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm getting the following when I try to do an npx create-next-app:

[image: Would you like to use TypeScript with this project]

I'm trying to work through some training that doesn't use TypeScript, but it won't let me select No for an answer.  I don't understand why it asks the question.

Another PC of mine doesn't ask me about TypeScript, so it must be a configuration issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't take no for an answer"? How did you try changing the selection to `No`? Worked fine on my end

Comment: I've tried entering "n", "N", "No", and "no", but nothing happens.

Comment: I was able to get aroudn this by adding a --js at the end of my command, but I don't understand why there's a yes/no option, but you can only answer yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`create-next-app` behaves somewhat differently from what many using NPM commands in the console may be used to. When this option comes up, it doesn't open up the console for input so that you can press `y` or `n` or something - instead, you have to use the arrow keys to toggle between the highlighted Yes and No. Press the left arrow key so No is highlighted, then press Enter.

Comment: this is not working in Windows using Git Bash

Comment: Same, not working on windows with Git Bash.

Comment: Update: Actually the arrow keys do work for Git Bash on Windows. It's just that it doesn't show on the output. You can just press an arrow key (it will stay on the default selection and will make you feel that it's not working but it actually moved the cursor) and press enter (it will again show the same output but this time underlined with the selection you chose).

Answer (score 0):

**create-next-app** When this option comes up, it doesn't open up the console for input so that you can press y or n or something - instead, you have to use the arrow keys to toggle between the highlighted Yes and No. *Press the left arrow key so No is highlighted, then press Enter.*

NB: Recommended to use ***Command Prompt*** instead of **git bash**